# jQuery- to get numbers1-8 instead of 0,4,7,9..etc

Tags: jquery

Thanks for all the help, but I just figured it out that how to make it look good.!!! I've learned a lot from here!

updated*
So I got this one combined from two people's code...and it needs to add the removing pic process or else the pics are over showing on the location.
please, I am almost there :s

For the img I've set this on css 
but when it is display:none, the pics wont show again, if I dont set the display then the pics just keep adding it up on the area.

```
  display: none;
 .is-active{
  display: block;
  }


$d
  .on('click','.accordion .r', (e)=>{

    const $targetImgNum = $(e.target).data('target');
    console.log($targetImgNum)
    $('.swing').append('<div class="switch"><img src="images/swing/'+($targetImgNum)+'.jpg" alt=""></div>')
  });
```

thanks for all the suppots,
your codes are worked but just not with my code.
if I choose h3 to be a selector, does it work well just like div?
I'm thinking because this is the only one spot is different from the codes you guys provided.

here's an example which Im trying to do...

https://jsfiddle.net/99v2gkp3/

The HTML Code

```
         <div class="accordion">
            <h3 class="r" show-id="img1"></h3>
              -----content has been deleted cuz it is irrelevant ----------
          </div>
      <div id='swingpic'>
         <div class="swing">
           <div ><img src="images/swing/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/7.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/9.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/13.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/15.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/17.jpg" alt=""></div>
           <div ><img src="images/swing/19.jpg" alt=""></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Since I am from overseas, please forgive if my grammar disturbs your eyes.

I'd like to get the numbers from 1-8 instead of the number which console.log shows me like 0,4,7,9,.....
I have 8 btns and each one shows one different pic.
Here the hint my teacher gave me

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  $(this).index()
  console.log(count)};
$(".pic").eq(count).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut()
```

please! I've tried creating a loop to get the right numbers but I just kept failing. :(

Comment: Where's your HTML?

Comment: Its quite long, so it simply is like  1 big div contains two divs(each is for pics and the btns)

Comment: If you want to use the given hint, so you have to add `btn` class to each div considered as a button and `pic` class to each img tag. take a look here  https://jsfiddle.net/8qL27cc7/

Comment: yes sir, I've done that as well..but when I apply the codes I got from here into mine, somehow it just doesn't work ;( I've asked my friends tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for something like this..
 http://jsfiddle.net/7xhxq/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.buttontest').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('img.logotest').toggle('slow');
    });
    });
```

Comment: you got the answer?

Comment: No sir, the btns are listed on the side, the pics show on one exact spot, so each time I click one btn it only shows one pic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function clickHandler(){ 
  var count = $(this).index();
  console.log(count);
  $(".pic").eq(count).fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
}

$('.btn').click(clickHandler);
 $('.pic').fadeOut(); // by default hiding all images on load
```

Html should be like this

```
<div class="btn-wrapper">
 <div class="btn"> 1</div>
 <div class="btn"> 2</div>
 <div class="btn"> 3</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrapper">
   <div class="pic" ><img src="images/swing/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="pic" ><img src="images/swing/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
   <div class="pic" ><img src="images/swing/7.jpg" alt=""></div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Console shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" :S

Comment: No it is not working, the console log doesn't provide the numbers at all :(

Comment: Also, you need to have btn and pic classes in you html.

Comment: add  class="pic" for each img container. Also add some btn in your html.  as <div class="pic"><img src="images/swing/1.jpg" alt=""></div>

Comment: I did follow your suggestion, but the screen is no change at all

Comment: In your html there is no classes as pic and btn, these classes must be there, for code to work properly.

Comment: the console shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }"

Comment: Yes sir, I've added those classes as you mentioned

Comment: I've found an error, and now there's no console shown but the pics changing still incorrect :(